# SQL - AVG Output is incorrect

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, sql-server-2008, average

In below query, I am calculating the lead time between two different dates and eventually trying to get the average of that lead time but the output is incorrect.

```
SELECT
Round(AVG(CAST(
Case when CONVERT(datetime, ORDERDATE, 105) = CONVERT(datetime, INVOUTDATE, 105) THEN 0 else
Case when CONVERT(datetime, ORDERDATE, 105) + 1 = CONVERT(datetime, INVOUTDATE, 105) THEN 1 else
(DATEDIFF(dd, CONVERT(datetime, ORDERDATE, 105), CONVERT(datetime, INVOUTDATE, 105)))
-(DATEDIFF(wk, CONVERT(datetime, ORDERDATE, 105), CONVERT(datetime, INVOUTDATE, 105))*1)
-(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, CONVERT(datetime, ORDERDATE, 105)) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
-(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, CONVERT(datetime, INVOUTDATE, 105)) = 'Sunday' THEN 0 ELSE 0 END) end end AS FLOAT)),4) AS LEADTIME FROM DSORDERSTATUS
WHERE ORDERTYPE <> 'Exchange Order' 
AND CONVERT(datetime, ORDERDATE, 105) between '20170801' and '20170831' 
AND CONVERT(datetime, INVOUTDATE, 105) IS NOT NULL
```

**To troubleshoot the above query I extract the data by using the same query below and when I manually calculate the lead time and average it was correct.
Don't know where is the issue? can someone please tell me whether anything wrong with my query.**
Please click on the link to refer sample data [Link](http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=g38c25e40dc7d1dac1000005713a97ade79820eb121)

```
SELECT DISTINCT DOCKETNO,
Case when CONVERT(datetime, ORDERDATE, 105) = CONVERT(datetime, INVOUTDATE, 105) THEN 0 else
Case when CONVERT(datetime, ORDERDATE, 105) + 1 = CONVERT(datetime, INVOUTDATE, 105) THEN 1 else
(DATEDIFF(dd, CONVERT(datetime, ORDERDATE, 105), CONVERT(datetime, INVOUTDATE, 105)))
-(DATEDIFF(wk, CONVERT(datetime, ORDERDATE, 105), CONVERT(datetime, INVOUTDATE, 105))*1)
-(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, CONVERT(datetime, ORDERDATE, 105)) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
-(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, CONVERT(datetime, INVOUTDATE, 105)) = 'Sunday' THEN 0 ELSE 0 END) end end AS LEADTIME FROM DSORDERSTATUS
WHERE ORDERTYPE <> 'Exchange Order' 
AND CONVERT(datetime, ORDERDATE, 105) between '20170801' and '20170831' 
AND CONVERT(datetime, INVOUTDATE, 105) IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: How is the output incorrect? Please add sample data, expected output and actual output.

Comment: The Data file is big..The expected output is 1.3078 but i am getting 1.4328. Also when i manually calculate using same query i got the correct output

Comment: Can you create a small data sample with the same issue?

Comment: can you try with a subset of data? for example `between '20170801' and '20170808' ` and then post the rows used?

Comment: You are extracting the data using `select distinct`.  You are taking the average of all the data.  The two data sets are not equivalent.

Comment: i have edited the post, please click on the link for sample data. I am getting 1.602 output but when i manually calculate the output was 1.2530

Comment: in your data there is still the DISTINCT clause, remove it and produce a new xlsx, please  use this query `SELECT DISTINCT ORDERDATE, INVOUTDATE FROM DSORDERSTATUS WHERE ORDERTYPE <> 'Exchange Order' AND CONVERT(datetime, ORDERDATE, 105) between '20170801' and '20170808' AND CONVERT(datetime, INVOUTDATE, 105) IS NOT NULL`

Comment: Okay i understood, when i remove the distinct and calculate the avg i got the same output which i was getting in query. But it is incorrect, please advise how should i calculate the correct avg in query????

Comment: why you say it is not correct? if you have two different orders with same date and same invoice date?

Comment: you should also post expected output of your data in excel.

Comment: Okay i will try to explain, in my data lets say customer has purchased 5 items which has generate the single order no but when i will calculate the lead time it will calculate the avg lead time of five lines which is incorrect because it is a single order.

Comment: i have uploaded one more sample file [Link](http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=g64d0b9a5a9f218bf100000572188f6c15b47d5d596) the avg of these shipments will be 1.60 then remove the duplicate of docket it will give 1.25 which i want in query

Comment: DOCKETNO IS THE ORDER_ID?

Comment: No orderid is different but doesn't matter what u select, both count is same.

Comment: with your dates and the query of my new answer I get 1.13

Comment: but in excel if you see it should be 1.25 right ?

Comment: I don't know.. I'm not using excel, but I have found a difference in your query you have `THEN 0 ELSE 0` for sundays `INVOUTDATE`

Answer (score 1):

ok, now I understand.. 
I think you have to group by orders before to calculate avg

```
;with
S AS (      
    select DOCKETNO, ORDERDATE, INVOUTDATE, COUNT(*) n
    from DSORDERSTATUS where ORDERTYPE <> 'Exchange Order' 
    group by DOCKETNO, ORDERDATE, INVOUTDATE
),
D as (
    select [DOCKETNO], [ORDERDATE], [INVOUTDATE],
        DATEDIFF(dd, CONVERT(date, [ORDERDATE], 105), CONVERT(date, [INVOUTDATE], 105)) dd,
        DATEDIFF(wk, CONVERT(date, [ORDERDATE], 105), CONVERT(date, [INVOUTDATE], 105)) wk,
        CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, CONVERT(datetime, ORDERDATE, 105)) = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END IsSundayOrd,
        CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw, CONVERT(datetime, INVOUTDATE, 105)) = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END IsSundayInv
    from S
)
select avg(cast(dd - case when dd>1 then (wk +  IsSundayOrd + IsSundayInv) else 0 end as float)) leadtime
from D
where CONVERT(date, ORDERDATE, 105) between '20170801' and '20170831' 
    AND CONVERT(date, INVOUTDATE, 105) IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: this is sql-server

Comment: Then why I am getting error while performing above code

Comment: Okay..I have left the office. Accessing this from Mobile. I will try tomorrow morning. Thanks for the help

Comment: I am getting conversion failed error, please see error screenshot. [Error](http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=gd8d8ee1267b1378f1000005983f2d9b16e06dbb56a)

Comment: `ORDERDATE` and `INVOUTDATE` are `VARCHAR` or `DATETIME` columns? I have updated the query, try it

Comment: Dear Mtwstark, with your query i am getting same output i.e. 1.24 even if i change the dates. But finally with your help i understood something and i have modified your query and with that query in every scenario i am getting correct output. thank you such. you are great

Answer (score 0):

I will try to convert your dates to `DATE` instesad of `DATETIME` I think you are filtering too much rows because '20170831' is '2017-08-31 00:00:00' and you are loosing all `ORDERDATE` between '00:00:00' and '23:59:59' (for '2017-08-31')

```
WHERE   ORDERTYPE <> 'Exchange Order' 
AND CONVERT(date, ORDERDATE, 105) between '20170801' and '20170831' 
AND CONVERT(date, INVOUTDATE, 105) IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for valuable revert but still i am getting same output

Comment: have you tryed to use `DATE` instead of `DATETIME` also inside the query?

Comment: I tried as per your suggestion but don't understand "Inside the Query"?? do u mean should i replace all datetime with date, if yes then yes i tried and got error

Answer (score 0):

With the help of MtwStark i was able to resolve this.
I have modified his query,
Thanks buddy

```
;with
S AS (
SELECT DISTINCT DOCKETNO,
Case when CONVERT(datetime, ORDERDATE, 105) = CONVERT(datetime, INVOUTDATE, 105) THEN 0 else
Case when CONVERT(datetime, ORDERDATE, 105) + 1 = CONVERT(datetime, INVOUTDATE, 105) THEN 1 else
(DATEDIFF(dd, CONVERT(datetime, ORDERDATE, 105), CONVERT(datetime, INVOUTDATE, 105)))
-(DATEDIFF(wk, CONVERT(datetime, ORDERDATE, 105), CONVERT(datetime, INVOUTDATE, 105))*1)
-(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, CONVERT(datetime, ORDERDATE, 105)) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)end end AS LEADTIME FROM DSORDERSTATUS
WHERE ORDERTYPE <> 'Exchange Order' 
AND CONVERT(datetime, ORDERDATE, 105) between '20170801' and '20170808' 
AND CONVERT(datetime, INVOUTDATE, 105) IS NOT NULL
),
D AS (
SELECT DOCKETNO, LEADTIME FROM S
)
SELECT AVG(CAST(LEADTIME AS FLOAT)) FROM D
```

Comment: can you please explain the meaning of `THEN 0 ELSE 0 END` for sundays of `INVOUTDATE`?

Comment: I guess it is just a useless. I am sorry i have removed it.

Comment: EUREKA! I have finally understood where is the problem! You have thousands of rows with `[DOCKETNO] = NULL` but with differents `[ORDERDATE]` and `[INVOUTDATE]` so, the problem is: how to handle this? are they of same order? is right to group them by dates?

Comment: yes group them is also work to extract the unique values but the qry shared by you in which first it's extracting the unique values then it is calculating the leadtime and then it is calculating the avg of that leadtime but every time it was giving me the same output even if i change the dates and the output was 1.24 so instead of that first i calculate the leadtime with distinct docket nos and then i select the leadtime column from S table and then use calculate the avg of that leadtime from D. Thanks this will help me in future. you are just gr8. with your logic only it was possible

Comment: I'm glad to have been useful :)